# Force OpenVPN to route all traffic through one IP address (2 IPs on same NIC)

Tags: centos, networking, routing, openvpn

I've trying to dig up a solution for this, but all I keep turning up is how to bind OpenVPN to a particular hardware interface. Not quite what I need to do here.

I run a server and I have 2 IPs at my disposal. I have my primary IP handling all general traffic (HTTP,Mail,SSH,etc). I want to have openvpn receive and originate traffic from my secondary IP so that I can keep my own personal usage separate from the regular server traffic. I already have it configured to only listen on the 2nd IP address, but all outgoing traffic is registering on my primary IP.

I'll admit, I've more or less got the basics down on operating a CentOS server, but this is one of the few things that's stumped me. I'm not afraid to get in and mess around with config files, but I'm no programmer/scripter.

So any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know about openvpn config details, but maybe you could solve this by using a network namespace. I.e., running openvpn with a namespace of a single virtual interface tied to your second IP.

Comment: Have you configured OpenVPN as a server or as a client to a remote server?

Comment: Howdy folks, I've installed it using yum, but it is configured to be a server as I use my laptop to connect to the VPN when I need to access it over an unknown Wi-Fi/LAN connection that I don't trust.